# I can only use nesting in Sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am not sure what I am missing, but I can only use **nesting** for in my rails files.  I want to be able to use **mixins** and **variables** as well.

My gem file is the includes sass:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

and my css files are name `custom.css.scss`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Sass doc:

> To install Sass in Rails 2, just add config.gem "sass" to
>   config/environment.rb. In Rails 3, add gem "sass" to your Gemfile
>   instead. .sass or .scss files should be placed in
>   public/stylesheets/sass, where they’ll be automatically compiled to
>   corresponding CSS files in public/stylesheets when needed (the Sass
>   template directory is customizable… see the Sass reference for
>   details).

I have to put the css files in a sass folder

Answer (score 0):

I expect you're doing something like `*= require_tree .` in your application.css.scss file to include your stylesheets.

According to the [official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), this won't work for mixins and variables:

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the
>   Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. Using
>   Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within their own scope,
>   making variables or mixins only available within the document they
>   were defined in

It kinda sucks, but you need to include them all individually, if you want the mixins and variables to work. Including them using `require` compiles more quickly than using `import`, and should be preferred unless there are shared variables or necessary dependencies.

**Example:**

```
//= require navigation
//= require icons
//= require buttons
@import "variables.css.scss";
@import "mixins.css.scss";
@import "something_else.css.scss";
```